# How to serialize a string into a Blob value without backslashes?

Tags: apex, map, string, wrapper-class

I have a `Map<string, String>` that is populated using the following code below. When I attempt to convert this into a serialized string so that it can be passed into `Blob.valueOf`, the `\"` (backslashes) are added to the values in the map. We want to remove those values in the map.

How can I pass the serialized string so that there are no backslashes?

Code:

```
public class MyWrapper {
  public String firstName;
  public String lastName;
}

Map<String, String> mapToSerialize = new Map<String, String>();
list<Contact> contactList = [Select Id, FirstName, LastName from Contact];
for(Contact cont : contactList) {
  MyWrapper contWrapper = new MyWrapper();
  contWrapper.firstName = cont.FirstName;
  contWrapper.lastName = cont.LastName;

  mapToSerialize.put(cont.Id, JSON.serialize(contWrapper));
}

response.responseBody = Blob.valueOf(JSON.serialize(mapToSerialize));
```

Current Output:

```
{
  "123123" : { \"FirstName\" : \"First Name\", \"LastName\" : \"the last name\" }
}
```

Desired output:

```
{
  "123123" : { "FirstName" : "First Name", "LastName" : "the last name" }
}
```

What I tried, but didn't work

1. added `response.addHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json')` but that returned the same output as `Current Output`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the given scenario, serialization occurs twice in the last three lines, and it is a cause of an observed scenario.

A better way to approach this could be using of `Map<String, Object>` instead of `Map<String, String>` and perform serialization once. It would works since any entity is an Object.

For example:

```
Map<String, Object> mapToSerialize = new Map<String, Object>();
list<Contact> contactList = [Select Id, FirstName, LastName from Contact];
for(Contact cont : contactList) {
  MyWrapper contWrapper = new MyWrapper();
  contWrapper.firstName = cont.FirstName;
  contWrapper.lastName = cont.LastName;

  mapToSerialize.put(cont.Id, contWrapper);
}

response.responseBody = Blob.valueOf(JSON.serialize(mapToSerialize));
```

Comment: using `Map<String, Object>` was the way to fix my problem. I no longer have backslashes